# Toast message showing behind the Semantic-UI modal when dimmer is set to {'blurring'}

Tags: reactjs, toast

I am using the toast messages in reachjs together with the semantic-ui. The problem is that the toast message is showing behind the modal when dimmer is set to blurring. Otherwise it is showing on the top of the page as expected.

Do you have the same issues? How this can be corrected?

Thanks for your help!

```
  <Modal
    centered
    size={'large'}
    open={this.props.openVariationGeometry}
    onClose={() => this.props.closeVariationGeometryModal()}
    closeIcon
    dimmer={'blurring'}
  >
    <Header icon="cube" content={'Change the Gemetry of the Selected Variation.'} />
    <Modal.Content>
      <VariationGeometryForm />
    </Modal.Content>
  </Modal>
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIUt2.png)

Answer (score 0):

define a css rule for your toast with `filter: none`, or a general rule like this

```
.toast-container {
  filter: none !important;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me. do you have another option please?

Answer (score 0):

It is very old question but I ended here looking for a solution to the same problem so I wrote this down. At first, as [this issue](https://github.com/academia-de-codigo/react-semantic-toasts/issues/29) says, the only way I found to show the toasts with a modal present is by putting the Toast Container inside the modal. This method has the problem that you could see also the "main" toast blurred under the modal.

Later I found a final solution [here](https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify/issues/139#issuecomment-1029812155). Both the toast container and the modal must be mounted on the same DOM node (I used `#App`).

First you have to put the toast container in the App component:

```
const App = () => (
    <div id='App'>
      <YourComponents />
      <ToastContainer
        className='dimmer toast-container' // 'dimmer' class is required to avoid blurring by modal
      />
    </div>
  
)
```

After that you need the following css rule:

```
.blurring.dimmable > .toast-container {
  // this prevents the toast from darkening by the modal
  background-color: unset;
}
```

And finally the modal must be mounted in the same node:

```
  <Modal
    centered
    size={'large'}
    open={this.props.openVariationGeometry}
    onClose={() => this.props.closeVariationGeometryModal()}
    closeIcon
    dimmer={'blurring'}
    mountNode={document.getElementById('App')} // modal mounted on #App
  >
    <Header icon="cube" content={'Change the Gemetry of the Selected Variation.'} />
    <Modal.Content>
      <VariationGeometryForm />
    </Modal.Content>
  </Modal>
```